# Is the <base> element safe to use?

Tags: html

I learned that it has some advantages to use this element, but it seems that no one around me us this element.  Is there any problem using this element?

Answer (score 0):

The  tag specifies the base URL and the target for all relative URLs in the document.
Meaning whatever links you pass in the whole document will lead to the URL that you've specified in the .

PROS

- while in the development phase you need not add multiple links for each link reference.

CONS

- Since it'll specify the URL for the whole document it restricts you to add different links. Therefore this tag is not popularly used.

Comment: What do you mean by "it restricts you to add different links?" There's nothing stopping you from adding absolute or relative links to a document that uses the `<base>` tag.